# Bootstrap 3 carousel transition speed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm running into a problem.

I've tried to do the following:

```
.carousel-inner > .item {
 position: relative;
 display: none;
 -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
 -moz-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
 -o-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
 transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
}


In the bootstrap.js:

.emulateTransitionEnd(600)
```

But it doesn't seem to work properly. The animation speeds up. But I use a carousel-caption that contains text, which bugs. It slides properly, but then the .content-caption moves all the way to the left, disappears, and appears in it's normal position.

Is there any other variable I need to change?

Answer (score 10):

visit: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Add the following on the end of your html-file to set the transition speed: 10000 (10sec)

```
 <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
 <script>
  $('.carousel').carousel({
   interval: 10000
  });
 </script>
```

Comment: That sets the time the carousel pauses on each slide, but I don't think it has anything to do with how fast a particular slide comes in and out which is what the OP was asking for.

Comment: Maybe not directly linked but the syntax may also apply to the other carousel properties. I was looking from a way to change the transition speed and this snippet works like a charm! Be sure to put the second script part after the html code that initializes the carousel otherwise no luck.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. This is the **interval** between images, not the **transition** time (the time during which the slide animation happens).

Comment: please understand what is question before you write answer

Comment: Sorry, this is unfortunately the wrong answer. after so many years, i still get news that i misunderstood the question :)

Answer (score 9):

Here is the very simple way;

Add `"data-interval="2000"` in the html. eg:`<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2000">`

Comment: This is also not the transition time, this is the pause interval on the slides themselves.

Comment: Would you know how to do add the `data-interval` to each item?

Answer (score 3):

To change the actual slide speed, not the transition time, since I use LESS, I found adding this to my custom.less (which imports all the other bootstrap LESS files first) worked:

```
@slideSpeed: 2s
.carousel-inner {
    > .item {
        .transition(@slideSpeed ease-in-out left);
        @media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
            transition: transform @slideSpeed ease-in-out;
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone like @ToolmakerSteve or myself in the future.

Turns out there's a constant in the bootstrap.js that I had to change to an option as well (see "duration" below)

```
  Carousel.DEFAULTS = {
  interval: 5000,
  pause: 'hover',
  wrap: true,
  keyboard: true,
  duration: 600
}
```

and replace:

```
    //.emulateTransitionEnd(Carousel.TRANSITION_DURATION)
    .emulateTransitionEnd(this.options.duration)
```

Then, I can add data-duration="1000" to my markup.

Comment: This is the only correct method and works for bootstrap 3.3.7 too.

Answer (score 0):

Those using bootstrap 4 scss can use this variable :)

```
$carousel-transition:           transform .6s ease-in-out !default;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Bootstrap 4.1

`#MyCarousel .carousel-item {
    transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}`

Change 1s to any duration.
Using an id for your carousel will automatically override Bootstrap, and allows you to use different speeds for different carousels.

Answer (score -1):

```
.carousel-inner>.item {
-webkit-transition: 0.9s ease-in-out left;
transition: 0.9s ease-in-out left;
-webkit-transition: 0.9s, ease-in-out, left;
-moz-transition: .9s, ease-in-out, left;
-o-transition: .9s, ease-in-out, left;
transition: .9s, ease-in-out, left;
}
```